# iterate over a map and change the position of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of object

```
const test = [{'type':'Material'}, {'type':''}, {'type':'ABC'}]
```

Here I am using map over here to itertae

```
export const mapToNA = values => map(test, value => type || 'NA')

mapToNA(test)
```

This returns the `[{'type':'Material'}, {'type':'NA'}, {'type':'ABC'}]`

Now I want value which is `NA` then it should be at the end

so Output would be like:

`[{'type':'Material'},{'type':'ABC'},{'type':'NA'}, ]`

How can I get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition the array to items with type, and items out without, and then map the relevant items' type to NA, and use spread to combine the arrays:

```js
const data = [{'type':'Material'}, {'type':''}, {'type':'ABC'}];

// Pertition items to have type and NA
const [itemsWithType, itemsWithEmptyType] = _.partition(data, o => o.type)

// map the itemsWithEmptyType to NA and combine
const result = [...itemsWithType, ...itemsWithEmptyType.map(o => ({ ...o, type: 'NA' }))]

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using lodash, lets use [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) with a custom function:

```js
// Data
let test = [{'type':'Material'}, {'type':''}, {'type':'ABC'}];

// Map '' to 'NA'
const mapToNA = values => _.map(test, value => { return { type: value.type || 'NA' }; } )
test = mapToNA(test)

// Sort
test = _.sortBy(test, element => (element.type === 'NA'));

// Log
console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

```json
[
  {
    "type": "Material"
  },
  {
    "type": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "type": "NA"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a custom sorting algorithm.

```js
const test = [
  { type: "ABC" },
  { type: "Material" },
  { type: "" },
  { type: "ABC" },
  { type: "" },
];
const result = test
  .map((s) => (s.type === "" ? { type: "NA" } : s))
  .sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.type === "NA" && b.type === "NA") return 0;
    if (a.type === "NA") return 1;
    if (b.type === "NA") return -1;
    else return 0;
  });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the order of the types will also get changed by this @decpk

Comment: @kishoreRajendran Thanks for the suggestion and corrected the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 separate arrays to keep track of objects with and without `type`. Merge them after the loop. This is readable and faster.

```js
const withType = [],
      withoutType = []
      
for (const o of test) {
  if (o.type)
    withType.push(o)
  else
    withoutType.push({ type: 'NA' })
}

console.log( withType.concat(withoutType) )
```

You could also `reduce` with 2 separate arrays and `flat` them:

```js
const group = test.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (o.type)
    acc[0].push(o)
  else
    acc[1].push({ 'type': 'NA' })
  return acc
}, [[], []])

console.log( group.flat() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default `sort` function from javascript to solve this.

```js
const arr =[{'type':'Material'}, {'type':'NA'}, {'type':'ABC'}];

arr.sort((a, b) => a["type"] === 'NA' ? 1 : -1);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to switch position between last element of array with your target element using Array.prototype.map ?
If so,

```
 const test = [{"type": "Material"}, {"type": "NA"}, {"type":"ABC"}];

const someFunction = values => {
   // NAIndex remember which index of values have "NA" 
   let NAIndex = 0;
   // copy original array values.
   const copiedValues = values.slice();
   return values.map((value,index) => {
    
   if(value["type"] === "NA"){
     NAIndex = index;
     return copiedValues[values.length-1];
   }
   else if(index === values.length-1){
     return copiedValues[NAIndex];
   }
   return value;
})
}

const array = someFunction(test);
console.log(array)

/*
(3) [Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
type: "Material"
1: Object
type: "ABC"
2: Object
type: "NA"
*/
```

only use map method is a bit give you constraints yourself. try use splice or something. using only map has low efficiency

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the array and then `sort` your array based on 'NA'

```js
const test = [{'type':'Material'}, {'type':''}, {'type':'ABC'}]

let result = test
  .map(val => ({type: val.type || 'NA'}))
  .sort((a,b) => a.type === 'NA' ? 1 : b.type === 'NA' ? -1 : 0);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `sort` function.

```
test.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    if (elem2.type !== 'NA')
            if (elem1.type === 'NA')
                    return 1
            else
                    return 0
    return -1
})
```

Or you can use the shorter one

```
test.sort((elem1, elem2) =>
    elem2.type !== 'NA' ? elem1.type === 'NA' ? 1 : 0 : -1)
```

Learn more about the sort method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).